# SLD - disable follow line

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I have a simple SLD style using in GeoServer v2.3.0 and testing in uDig.  I have a interstate symbol that I **do not** want the label symbol to follow the line.  I thought if I set:

```
<sld:VendorOption name="followLine">false</sld:VendorOption>
```

It would ignore this parameter.

[image]

How do I make my labels ignore followline?

Comment: what happens if you remove the line completely?

Comment: @iant, Same result (I'm testing it within uDig).

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @mbosecke, yes I did not use any vendor options just the x and y anchor points.

Comment: Thanks! For me it turns out it was the "PerpendicularOffset" that was triggering the labels to follow the line (which makes sense). Removing this offset fixed it for me.